# Log4net doesn't create a log file as using via private nuget package in .NET5

Tags: c#, log4net, .net-5

I have a simple Logger class library in .net 5

```
 <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
```

The Logger logs by using log4net version 2.0.15

I created a simple .net5 console app (as above) and add the reference to the Logger project.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

       Logger.Logger.Log("Start");;
   
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
}
```

**Excepted Result:**

Create a log file with the Start written in.

**Actual Result:**

created the log file with the Start word in it.

Now I packed the Logger to a private nuget package and instead of referencing the project, I installed the nuget package.

**Excepted Result:**

Create a log file with the Start written in.

**Actual Result:**
Didn't create the log file.

It occurs only in .NET 5, testing the above on .net framework works fine.

Is it a bug in .NET or log4net?

Thx.